# CSV file from HDFS to Oracle BLOB using Spark

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark

I'm working on Java app that uses Spark 2.3.1 to load data from Oracle to HDFS and vice versa. 
I want to create CSV file in HDFS and then load it to Oracle (12.2) BLOB.

The code..

```
        //create Dataset
        Dataset<Row> dataset = SparkService.sql("select * from test_table");
        String trgtFileWithPath = "/tmp/test_table.csv";      

        //save file in HDFS
        dataset.write().mode("overwrite").format("csv").save(trgtFileWithPath);

        //get file from HDFS
        JavaSparkContext jsc = SparkContextUtil.getJavaSparkContext("appId");
        JavaRDD<String> textFile = jsc.textFile(trgtFileWithPath);

        //Call Oracle package, that inserts into table with BLOB field
        File csvFile = new File("/tmp/ETLFramework/test_table1.csv");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(csvFile), 500);
        Connection conn = tbl.getJdbcConnection(); //there is tbl var with java.sql.Connection
        CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(String.format("{call %s(?, ?, ?)}", "ORACLE_API_FOR_ETL_FRAMEWORK.INSERT_LOB"));
        cstmt.setString(1, "FILE_TO_LOB");
        cstmt.setString(2, "/tmp/test_table.csv");
        cstmt.setClob(3, bis, (int) csvFile.length());
        cstmt.execute();

        if (!conn.getAutoCommit()) {
            conn.commit();
        }
```

I'm new to Spark.. so any ideas please how to convert JavaRDD to BufferedInputStream, or get rid of mess above and put Dataset to Oracle BLOB in more sane way..

Thanks

Comment: I can't make sense of your code (or pseudo-code). You use the same path `/tmp/test_table.csv` for (a) a _directory_ in HDFS _(assuming that the default FS of Spark is indeed HDFS and not a S3 bucket or tthe local FS in local mode)_ where each Spark executor will write 0..N files, one per Spark partition of the dataset and (b) on the local filesystem of the Oracle server, since you use it from within a stored proc.  And there's that mysterious `/tmp/ETLFramework/test_table1.csv` that you read from. Confusing

Comment: To be more specific, I can't make sense of your architecture -- where does Spark run, where does HDFS run, where does Oracle run -- and what kind of Oracle connector you are using _(I guess an OCI connector has more features for BLOB handling than the standard "thin" JDBC driver, although I did not play with any of these for many years)_

Comment: Spark, HDFS and Oracle each running on a separate machine. Jar files of app are located on Spark machine. Spark-submit is used to start app. 
java.sql.Connection is used to connect to Oracle and call stored procs with BLOB params.

Comment: My task is to convert Spark Dataset into CSV and insert it into Oracle BLOB.

Comment: Try to clarify architecture: To write CSV file generated from Spark Dataset<Row> to HDFS ("/tmp/test_table.csv") I use `String trgtFileWithPath = "/tmp/test_table.csv"; dataset.write().mode("overwrite").format("csv").save(trgtFileWithPath);` Then I read that CSV file from HDFS: `JavaRDD<String> textFile = jsc.textFile(trgtFileWithPath);`

Comment: This mysterious `File csvFile = new File("/tmp/ETLFramework/test_table1.csv");` is just an example CSV file created manually on machine where Spark is running (not where the HDFS datanodes running) to load it into BLOB using Java.io.BufferedInputStream. I want to write JavaRDD<String> textFile to BLOB in the same way that csvFile been loaded- using java.sql.CallableStatement: `cstmt.setClob(3, bis, (int) csvFile.length());` Or get rid of this mess and load Spark Dataset<Row> in CSV format to Oracle BLOB in more adequate way. Thanks!

Comment: So in reality you don't need HDFS at all -- except maybe as the back-end storage for Hive in the initial `select * from test_table` query. You can tell Spark to write the CSV file(s) to the local filesystem of the Spark server as `file:///tmp/test_table.csv/`. But you will still have **multiple files in a directory**. If you want a single CSV, just stop messing around with a distributed processing framework and use a plain Java program. Formatting the content of a JDBC resultset is not that complicated.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Plain Java for reading files and inserting them into BLOB is perfectly Ok, but not in our architecture.. When Java app starts using Spark-Submit, it doesn't run on machine where Spark is running, it runs on one of four datanodes (In prod there are 20 datanodes). So I have to create on every datanode tmp folder to store files created by Spark.. Maybe there is some way to make Java app run exactly on machine with Spark so there will be no need to create bunch of folders to store these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally.. after couple days of fighting with Oracle, Hadoop and Spark, I found solution for my task:

```
        try {
        String trgtFolderPath = "tmp/ETLFramework/csv/form_name";
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String hdfsUri = "hdfs://" + /*nameNode*/ + ":" + /*hdfsPort*/;
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(URI.create(hdfsUri), conf);
        RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> fileStatusListIterator = fileSystem.listFiles(new Path(trgtFolderPath), true);
        while(fileStatusListIterator.hasNext()){
            LocatedFileStatus fileStatus = fileStatusListIterator.next();
            String fileName = fileStatus.getPath().getName();
            if (fileName.contains(".csv") && fileStatus.getLen()>0) {
                log.info("fileName=" + fileName);
                log.info("fileStatus.getLen=" + fileStatus.getLen());
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fileSystem.open(new Path(trgtFolderPath + "/" + fileName)), 500);

                ETLParams param = ETLParams.getParams();
                Connection conn = tbl.getJdbcConnection();
                String apiPackageInsertLOB = ETLService.replaceParams(tbl.getConnection().getFullSchema() + "." + tbl.getApiPackage().getDbTableApiPackageInsertLOB(), param.getParamsByName());
                log.info(String.format("Call %s(%s, %s, %s);", apiPackageInsertLOB, tbl.getFullTableName(), trgtFolderPath + "/" + fileName, "p_nInsertedRows"));
                CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(String.format("{call %s(?, ?, ?, ?)}", apiPackageInsertLOB));
                cstmt.setString(1, tbl.getFullTableName());
                cstmt.setString(2, trgtFolderPath + "/" + fileName);
                cstmt.setBlob(3, bis, fileStatus.getLen());
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
                cstmt.execute();
                int rowsInsertedCount = cstmt.getInt(3);
                log.info("Inserted " + rowsInsertedCount + " rows into table blob_file");
                cstmt.close();
            }
        }
        fileSystem.close();
    }
    catch (IOException |
           SQLException exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Writing of 2 Gb CSV from Spark Dataset into HDFS, and following reading of this CSV from HDFS into Oracle BLOB took about 5 minutes..